# How to override Laravel Voyager migrations files?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I am currently working on a project and I have already built a ALC system with users and roles. Lately I tried to install Voyager but Voyager has his own users and roles system.

How can I override it's migrations files to disable it somehow from creating those  particles tables such as users roles permissions? Kind of disable that particular roles and permissions system because I want to use my own.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained on Installation Manual, advanced section: https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/getting-started/installation

And the voyager's migration path is: /vendor/tcg/voyager/migrations